# How to see the lines whose date column is less than x day from today

Tags: shell-script, awk, date

My file

```
ID=29524 02/12/2015,23:59:34,'PAt, 0,
ID=29628 02/12/2015,23:59:37,'PAb, 1.9,
ID=30816 03/12/2015,00:00:20,'PAc, 4.15,
```

I would like to print files with X days less than from today.

My try is bellow:

```
cat response.txt | awk -v start=$(date -d "-5 days" +%d/%m/%Y) -F" " '{split($2, a, /\//)} (a[3] a[1] a[2] <start)'| cut -d, -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed when you said X days less than today, you mean files "older than 5 days." If you mean files exactly 5 days, the script below would need to be modified to drop the time stamp most likely and -lt could be replaced with -eq

```
#!/bin/bash

CUTOFF=$(date +%s -d "5 days ago")

while read p; do
   time=$(echo $p | awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $2" "$3}')
   epoch_time=$(date --date="$time" +%s) 

   if [ $epoch_time -lt $CUTOFF ]; then
   echo $p
   fi;
done <response.txt
```

The above will load response.txt and loop through each line in the file. Awk is parsing by space and comma into separate columns and then printing the date and time. After that (probably could be done in the same line), it converts the date/time to a epoch time in seconds. After that, it's a simple matter of comparing the cutoff time in seconds to file time through an if statement.

The above will only print files **older than 5 days**.